# Very strange overload failure

Tags: c++

I have encountered a very strange overload failure. I am able to isolate the problem, but I cannot for the life of it figure out what goes wrong.

The code is the following

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class X>
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(const std::initializer_list<X> &A){}
  Foo(size_t n){}
};

class Bar
{
public:
  Bar() = default;
  Bar(const Foo<size_t> &A, bool a=true, bool b=true){};
};

int main()
{
  Bar A({1,2});
}
```

Compiling results in

```
$ clang++ -std=c++14 so.cpp

so.cpp:21:11: error: call to constructor of 'Bar' is ambiguous
      Bar A({1,2});
          ^ ~~~~~
so.cpp:12:11: note: candidate is the implicit move constructor
    class Bar
          ^
so.cpp:12:11: note: candidate is the implicit copy constructor
so.cpp:16:7: note: candidate constructor
      Bar(const Foo<size_t> &A, bool a=true, bool b=true){};
      ^
1 error generated.
```

The two things that get rid of the problem are:

- Removing `Foo(size_t n)`.
- Changing the constructor to `Bar(const Foo<size_t> &A)`.

*Obviously I want to keep all features. So: What goes wrong? How can I solve it?*

Comment: Adding an `explicit` to your Bar ctor seems to fix it.

Comment: @Arcinde Thanks a lot, that solves the problem. It does remain unclear to me as to why this is needed in this case.

Comment: Try `Bar A{{1,2}};`

Comment: `Bar A{1, 2};` compiles. But I am not sure if that gives you what you want.

Comment: @G_S it calls wrong constructor

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264846/can-the-explicitness-of-a-constructor-supposedly-be-ignored-due-to-the-form-of-i

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an explicit constructor with a braced-init list: ambiguous or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622076/calling-an-explicit-constructor-with-a-braced-init-list-ambiguous-or-not)

Comment: @KillzoneKid Thanks for the suggestion on the duplicate. It's surely related, but I think not one-to-one. In any case, the case that I present is not a compiler bug, or at least GCC displays exactly the same error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What goes wrong?

```
Bar A({1,2});
```

Can be interpreted as:

```
Bar A(Bar{Foo<std::size_t>(1), (bool)2 /*, true*/ });
```

or

```
Bar A(Foo<std::size_t>{1,2} /*, true, true*/);
```

so ambiguous call.

> How can I solve it?

It depends of which result you expect, adding `explicit` might help for example.

Making `explicit Foo(size_t n)` would allow only:

```
Bar A(B{Foo<std::size_t>(1), (bool)2 /*, true*/ });
```

Comment: Why does the compiler give the implicit move ctor of `Bar` as a candidate then?

Comment: syntax `{..}` allows to call non explicit constructor.

Comment: @Jarod42 I mean, the candidates you wrote in your answer are different from the ones the compiler gave.

Comment: Simply adding `explicit` doesn't compile in GCC https://ideone.com/zR1dTZ

Comment: There are 2 ways to force `initializer_list` constructor, either explicitly `Bar A(std::initializer_list<size_t>{1,2})`or by using curly brackets `Bar A{{1,2}}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes it clearer. I realize that 'best' solution depends on my needs, which is this case making the `Bar` constructor `explicit`, as proposed by @KillzoneKid. In any case, your answer might be more complete if that option is included?

Comment: @TomdeGeus Brace initializer {...} is what you need to call all and any of your constructors and it should also save you some headache in the future https://ideone.com/0DQF5X

Comment: @KillzoneKid Thanks! That is very instructive.